# How to convert Custom Objects to NSString in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I am using Objective C Proxy objects(which was created using wsdl2Objc tool) to access SOAP Based web services.

It is a .Net based Web service. It returns XML data.

The C# based Proxy Objects for accessing that web service is working properly.

```
@interface EmployeeDetails{
    NSString name;
    NSString *empID;
    }
    @end

    @interface CommonRequest{
    NSString *sessionID;
    NSString *employeeDetails;
    }
    @end
```

In C# proxy object the type of the field is another custom object whereas in Objective C the type is NSString.

How to convert Custom object(of type EmployeeDetails) into its NSString equivalent(employeeDetails)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to parse the XML, and optionally create an object or `NSDictionary` representation from it. Search the documentation for `NSXML` or `CFXML` APIs.

To use an `EmployeeDetails` instance to represent a string in a `CommonRequest`, you will need to find out what the API expects (you can print the C# `CommonRequest` to find out, or better, refer to its implementation to see how it builds the string).